# On Catalina, how can a cronjob get permission to touch files on a USB disk?

Tags: macos, catalina, cron

I have a USB disk, that takes ages to spin up after it has gone to sleep. So in the past I used either a cron job to regularly touch a file on it, so it will never spin down.

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/touch /Volumes/xxx/touch.txt >/tmp/stdout.log 2>/tmp/stderr.log
```

Only since Catalina, these jobs get a `touch: /Volumes/xxx/touch.txt: Operation not permitted`.
When I use the same command in the console, it works nicely.

I had to grant the terminal access full disk access. Is there a similar restriction on this cron task?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to grant cron full disk access. Drag /usr/sbin/cron into the Full Disk Access area in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy tab.

Source: https://twitter.com/DaveWoodX/status/1184235412509941761

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew it had to be something like that!

Comment: Thanks. Why does Apple have to make this so difficult!

Comment: Jesus, thank you for this. Took me way too long to ask the right question and then find the relatively simple solution. :+1:

Comment: It’s amazing what you can pick up by being in the right place at the eight time in Twitter.